# How to start my Application on Server startup

Tags: c#, windows-services, startup

I have a Windows Forms Application which runs on a server. I need this Application to always start automatically. Even if the Server just gets restartet and nobody logs into it the Application should run.
So the solutions with Registry don´t work here. I than read into Windows Services but it seems like I can´t start a WinForm Application with it.

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this automatic Start on Server startup?

Comment: So, if nobody has logged into the server, how is a WinForms application going to be useful?  Who is it going to interact with?  How is it going to interact with anyone?

Comment: You should run a service if nobody is logged on, you can always execute a windows form startup whenever someone does logon, but like Mike Nakis also said, no logon = no interaction, so you dont need the form.

Comment: See this link 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-start-program-before-user-logon-windows-7/2bff97c4-c037-437c-9fa7-b143a3ae5189?auth=1

Comment: @MikeNakis Its an Application which creates default folders wherever I put for example a new folder with name 1. So every Workstation can just create a folder on the networkdrive and the application puts the default directories with files to it. Should I solve this differently? The first time the user has to choose the locations where the application should look what is possible in the form if a folder is chosen the program just starts and stays in the background. thanks for the fast answers your awesome :D

Comment: When you go to build your Windows Service I suggest you look into [Top shelf](http://topshelf-project.com) which will make it much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we do things like that is that we create a Windows Service which runs without the need to have anyone logged in, and then if there is a need we have a separate GUI application (WinForms in your case) which interacts with the service, when needed.

The communication between the GUI application and the Windows Service is usually done by means of named pipes, but if you can get away with something simpler, like the GUI application saving a configuration file for the service to pick up, you might make it easier for you.

Comment: thank you alot. Just needed the clarification how to do things like that :) have a nice day